# Meanings of parameters when generating pre-signed URL using boto S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I am using `boto` to create pre-signed URLs to permission users to upload directly to S3.

I know that we can use `generate_url` method (available both for Connection and Bucket classes) for this, but it's not clear to me what some of the available parameters such as `headers`, `response_headers`, and `force_http` specifically mean in that method.

I guess that `headers` are the headers in the request to the URL generation? And `response_headers` are the ones that will be in the response when the file is downloaded?

As for `force_http`, which connection is it for? Is it the connection between my application and aws, or the connection between the uploading client and aws?

Answer (score 0):

> force_http

will force non SSL http connection (e.g. not https).   This is for the resulting URL

> headers (e.g. generate_url(headers='X-Forward-For: 1.2.3.4')

will set the headers for the request, maybe passing a aws token for auth or something

> response_headers

will override the default response headers from the S3 object, maybe you want to have a header in the response that your receiving client will interpret.

Details can be seen here:  http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/gs.html?highlight=generate_url#boto.gs.key.Key.generate_url